How to detect the changes on selected text in chrome extension

In my chrome extension I am storing the selected text of user in local storage but the problem is that when I close the popup and reopen the popup in text area the selected text is removed.
How I can check for changes in selected text after the page reload?

I want when the user click on start button and then page will reload in DOM check the selected text that was selected by the user before reload is same or change.

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
